# node js net library - get info about the client(socket)

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, typescript, socket.io

I use nodejs cluster with socket.io, and in the master thread I use the built in net library to listen on a port and pass the connection(socket) manually to the workers (based on the client's ip address, so if the client reconnect to the server the client will join to the same worker). This is working well, but I would like to test, and I want to join to different worker from localhost.

Is there any way to get info about the client (e.g. browser name, custom parameter) or anything else to make different between two or more clients from localhost? - It could be cool if I'm be able to join the client to a worker based on the browser (chrome clients goes to worker 1, firefox clients goes to worker 2) on development environment.

```
private createServer(): void {
    var self = this;

    this.masterServer = net.createServer(<any>{ pauseOnConnect: true }, (connection) => {
        console.log('server', connection);

        let worker = self.workers[self.getWorkerIndex(connection.remoteAddress, self.workerCount)];
        worker.send('privateCon', connection);

    }).listen(self.serverPort);
}
```

Comment: This is a bit difficult as the connection has to happen before any extra protocol information is available. What OS are you aiming for this to work on?

Comment: Source IP, source TCP Port and destination IP are 3 things you do have

Comment: the dev env is windows 10. Source ip, tcp port and dedtination ip are the same on any connection from localhost.

Comment: The source/dest ip can be changed to anything in the 127.0.0.0/8 range though, which all point to the loopback interface.  You can already `ping 127.0.0.2`. As long as you are not listening on a specific 127 address,  you can connect to different addresses and should be able to pick that address up in `connection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows and Linux the entire 127.0.0.0/8 range works on the loobback interface by default so you could differentiate connections by their destination or `localAddress` as long as your server is not listening on one specific address.

Run a simple server

```
$ node -e 'net.createServer(connection => {
    console.log(connection.remoteAddress, connection.remotePort, connection.localAddress)
}).listen(8082)'
```

Then connect with something like `telnet` or `nc` or even `node`.

```
$ node -e 'client = net.connect(8082, "127.0.0.4", ()=> client.end())'
```

OSX always gets a connection mapped to IPv6 even when specifying IPv4, not sure if you will get that on Windows too, but the output from the server should read something like:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.4 57290 ::ffff:127.0.0.4
```

So you could use something for your connection handler like

```
switch (connection.localAddress){
  case '::ffff:127.0.0.1':  return worker1
  case '::ffff:127.0.0.2':  return worker2
  case '::ffff:127.0.0.3':  return worker3
  case '::ffff:127.0.0.4':  return worker4
  default: return lookupWorker()
}
```

Comment: Just note, if anyone try this with webpack 2, you have to set the host to 0.0.0.0, because the default is 127.0.0.1. So you can add this: --host 0.0.0.0

Comment: I guess if you were stuck listening on 127.0.0.1 you could differentiate on the source address, but there's less support for specifying a source address in clients. I'm not sure if browsers like chrome or firefox support that.